# How to have the UID generated from Facebook auth on Firebase consistently persisted throughout my application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my login screen, the user logs in through facebook and a unique UID is generated for the current logged in user. I then store the information I need in firebase with a child called user and then each child within user is in the form {uid: {name:blah, email:blah, phone:blah}}

After storing this data in Firebase, I want to redirect the page to my form.ejs page. However, I want to have access to the UID so that I can query the db for the current user later in the application.

How do I have this UID persist throughout my application because the moment I do location.href = './form' I lose access to that global variable UID that I have saved.

Secondly, I am doing all this saving to data and redirecting from the client side in the .js file. Should I instead be doing this all from the server (app.js)?? I am currently creating a json object with the data I need from FB and then simply calling firebase and saving the child. Should I create an ajax request instead and send it to my server with a post request and then navigate to the form.js page?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't either store it in a cookie on the client or in a session value on the server and, like you say, request it using ajax?